# $\sqrt{T^\ast T}$ is positive

Tags: linear-algebra

I read that $\sqrt{T^\ast T}$ is positive operator. I tried to proof it but fail. Is it not true that $\sqrt{T^\ast T}$ is positive? If it is true anyone can show me how to proof it please? Positive mean that $$ \langle \sqrt{T^\ast T} v,v \rangle \ge 0$$
for all $v \in V$. The $T$ is a linear operator $T:V\to V$.

Comment: It's the definition of $\sqrt{T^\ast T}$. Can you see that $T^\ast T$ is a symmetric/hermitian positive operator? Then $\sqrt{T^\ast T}$ is _defined_ as the unique(?) positive operator $S$ with $S^2 = T^\ast T$.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel wrote, it's a definition:

> $\sqrt{T^*T}$ is a unique positive semidefinite matrix such that $(\sqrt{T^*T})^2 = T^*T$.

What is there to prove is:

1. $T^*T$ is positive semidefinite,
2. There always exists a positive semidefinite $X$ such that $X^2 = T^*T$ (hint: the eigenvalue decomposition),
3. Such $X$ is unique (hint: assume that it is not, and go back to the eigenvalue decomposition).

If you need help with any of these, ask in the comments.

Comment: Does this question make any sense if $V$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: @StefanSmith I think the question does make sense, since all the terms do exist there. However, I don't deal with the infinite-dimensional spaces, so I don't know what would be the answer to it. You might want to open a new question for that.